# How to decode decoded files after downloading from Azure Storage?

Tags: java, azure, decode, azure-blob-storage, encode

I am trying to decode files after downloading via Azure Storage SDK for Java.

Here is my code:

```
try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("mycontainer");
            CloudBlobDirectory blobDirectory = container.getDirectoryReference("shi");
            for (ListBlobItem blobItem : blobDirectory.listBlobs()) {
                if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
                    CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItem;
                    blob.download(new FileOutputStream("/Users/shi/Downloads/" + blob.getName()));
                }
            }
        }
```

This code downloads all the BLOB files from mycontainer but there are encoded. How can I download them but in decoded form.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by "blobs are encoded"?

Comment: When you see the file with text editor, you see some ascii codes like: õ∂πñsÎÅ”·ñÇYt‹.... There were not in the file before sending file to Azure Storage

Comment: Can you check the content-encoding property of these blobs? Looks like they are zipped at the time of uploading using GZip compression. Other reason could be that they are encrypted and uploaded. How did you upload these files? Please share that as well.

Comment: my colleague uses Azure SDK and AVRO to send the files to Azure Storage. That is all information which I know.

Comment: @Sohrab Any progress now?

Comment: No. We try to save data in Azure as binary. It was JSON. I don't know what is the problem. But I guess, my colleague did something that it is not suitable for this platform. Thank you so much for your comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

```
public static int convertAvro(String avroFile) throws Exception {

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out);
    GenericDatumReader<Object> reader=new GenericDatumReader<Object>();
    org.apache.avro.file.FileReader<Object>  fileReader=  DataFileReader.openReader(new File(avroFile),reader);
      try {
        Schema schema=fileReader.getSchema();
        // System.out.print(schema);
        DatumWriter<Object> writer=new GenericDatumWriter<Object>(schema);
        JsonEncoder encoder=EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema,out);
        for (Object datum : fileReader)     writer.write(datum,encoder);
        encoder.flush();
        out.println();
        out.flush();
      }
      finally {
        fileReader.close();
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue.

My sample code ：

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("jay");
   for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
        if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
            CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItem;
            blob.download(new FileOutputStream("E://AzureFile/" + blob.getName()));
```

Download successfully ：

[image]

You can see check if the blob Content Type is text/plain in Storage Explorer first. Blob specific Content Type is not displayed on the portal.

[image]

In addition , it might because of the encoding you use when you parse blob content is inconsistent with the encoding your colleague use when the blob is uploaded.

This issue is encountered when downloading text, but the binary does not.

I suggest you get the encoding when the file was uploaded and set the character set to parse the blob content by using the following sample snippet of code:

```
if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
      CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItem;
      InputStream input =  blob.openInputStream();
      InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
      String utf8str = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(inr);
      System.out.println(utf8str);
}
```

Hope it helps you.